# How to use complex numbers in c++?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

may you tell me how to write a complex variable in C++ code please?

I do have separate real part psi_rl and imaginary part psi_im. Now I have to write psi = psi_rl + i psi_im. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: is this a learning exercise or have you considered using std::complex?

Comment: Apache has some nice examples at http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/20-2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation for `std::complex`, it will give you answers to these questions and many more.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I will go over it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should give you the basic idea:

```
class complex
{
public:
    double real;
    double imag;
    complex(double real, double imag): real(real), imag(imag) {};
    complex operator+(complex c) { return complex(this->real+c.real, this->imag+c.imag); };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    complex a(1,2);
    complex b(-3,6);
    complex c = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you David. Actually I am beginner of C++ and do write the plain codes. I have not used the classes in my program Do you think I can find the way to write the complex number with my real and imaginary part please? Thank you.

Comment: print out the real and imag members